# How to create a Angular material tree using Dynamic data coming from the angular services

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am very new to angular . I am trying this example to create tree. Here is the link.
I tried to implement the same ex in my project with the same tree data.
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwiUW.png)
https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnndeajnmkvp?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts

But I am not getting the expected results as shown in the example. Expand and collapse are not working,I am seeing dots in UI which is not in tree data. I have attached the screenshot. What might have been gone wrong am i missing anything in tree configuration.....??

Comment: Please provide a basic stackblitz of the code you have tried so far

Comment: @SiddharthaGupta  have updated my question. Please can you help me out

Comment: The stackblitz seems to be working fine... It looks more likely a CSS issue.. Inspect and see if the 'list-style-type' is missing on the 'li' elements... It's hard to comment without looking at your css code

Answer (score 1):

the diference between use a static value or data from a service is that you need subscribe to the service to get the data. I transform the the example of [the example of material](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview#flat-tree) in  [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qrasi?file=app/data.service.ts)

If you look the differences are

1.-In constructor add the service

```
constructor(private dataService:DataService){}
```

2.- implements OnInit and in ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res=>{
        this.dataSource.data = res;
    })
  }
```

Well, in the example I use the 'rxjs' operator "of" to create an observable, you generally used `this.httpClient.get(...your-url..)`